# QuickFIX: Is it possible to log in multiple accounts under single connection?

Tags: quickfix

I am managing an existing FIX client application that uses **QuickFIX** library to connect to various FIX servers.

When a user wants to connect and login an account to server, the client app uses separate connection with its own configuration `(.cfg)` file. App currently does not allow to connect multiple users that means to create multiple connections with separate accounts.

My question is if there is a possibility to connect and login multiple separate accounts (*users with different usernames and passwords*) under single connection to FIX server?

Thanks for any advice.

P.S.: I now that there can be multiple sessions under one connection but sessions must be linked with single master account and that is not what I want.

Comment: Messages are session specific. So if multiple users are in a session than  do it outside quickfix, which is easier and divides up responsibilities. Sort of a message accumulator who keeps who sent which message and then decides responses go to which user. Adding all of this logic to quickfix, can be done, but is counter intuitive and will invite trouble.

Comment: I don't think that this can solve my problem because still I am not able to send messages from various accounts through single connection of another account. I am looking for a way that I can login accounts in separate sessions but under single connection to server.